# SQL: Write a query that given a varchar, find if it exists in column A or column B

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table with two columns, A and B

```
CREATE table test(
    A VARCHAR(20)
    B VARCHAR(20)
);

INSERT into A 
VALUES
('cat'), ('dog'),('cow'), ('horse')

INSERT into A 
VALUES
('chicken'), ('steve'),('fish'), ('eel')
```

I want to write a query where given a varchar, it would return the column name where it exists (returns an empty varchar if neither). A and B does not have any identical varchars. I'm relatively new with mySql.

find('cat') returns 'A'

find('eel') returns 'B'

find('goat') returns ''

Comment: update your question add  a real data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: Do you have any sql you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `WHERE` to filter to the row containing your variable.  Then a `CASE` statement for the logic.

```
SELECT
   CASE 
    WHEN A = [your varchar] THEN 'A'
    WHEN B = [your varchar] THEN 'B'
    END
FROM test
WHERE A = [your varchar] OR B = [your varchar]
```

Note: this will return no rows if the variable is not present.  And if the variable is present multiple times, it'll return one row for every occurrence.  Finally, if it is found in both columns, this query will only return "A" since `CASE` statements are checked in order written.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN A='input' THEN 'A' 
     WHEN B='input' THEN 'B' 
     ELSE '' END AS 'ColumnName' 
FROM test WHERE A = 'yourString' OR B = 'yourString'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple case should do:

```
select 
   case when A='input' then 'A' 
        when B='input' then 'B' 
        else 'None' end as 'ColumnName' 
 from Table
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this

```
SET @c = 'Z';
SELECT 
    IfNull((SELECT 'A' FROM Test WHERE A = @c LIMIT 1), '')
    + 
    IfNull((SELECT 'B' FROM Test WHERE B = @c LIMIT 1), '')
```

That way you'll only get 1 row, and it'll be 'A', 'B', 'AB' (if both), '' (if none)